# Two dimensions Array with getter and setter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Currently my code look something like this

```
var person = [];
person["firstName"] = "John";
person["lastName"] = "Doe";
```

I want to implement something like this

```
person[1]["firstName"] = "John";
person[1]["lastName"] = "Doe";

person[5]["firstName"] = "Tiger";
person[5]["lastName"] = "Din";
```

the structure is based on my database product id,

```
person[product_id]["firstName"] = val;
```

I want to able to fetch the record by calling this

```
Alert("Val is  " + person[5]["firstName"]);
```

it will echo out the first name which is Tiger, would it be fine if I don't start my array from [0] , and jump from [1] to [5].

Is there a way I can implement the whole array in just 1 var sentence like
and get the value of first name and last name by having the value of id

```
var person = [{id:1;firstName:John;lastName:doe},{id:2,firstName:Tiger;lastName:din;}];
```

Thanks for helping !!

Comment: What you really want to do?

Comment: ...and what exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem . How do I set the array and get first Name and last Name by "id" , I want set it like a serialise array, everything element in 1 var

Comment: Is it PHP or JS ? It is possible in PHP with associative array, where keys are what-ever-you-want, so it can start at index 4 if you wish to. In JS I don't think it is as simple.

Comment: @Random its js. yes I can do it with php, but not with js, I wonder how do I get value of an array element by providing it id as the key to draw it other variable like first Name and last Name

Comment: You can make 2 arrays. One containing the association between indexes and ids (index 0 contains id 1, index 1 contains id 4...), and the second one with the data you want (index 0 contains John Doe, and is about id 1 (known from the first array...) could that help ?

Comment: @Random, definitely if by providing the id I can get the last Name and first Name then its good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an array of object. You just have to define it the right way. In the function I made here you can call any attribute in an object you want. I gave 3 examples how you can use it.

```
var person = [{id:1,firstName:'John',lastName:'doe'},{id:2,firstName:'Tiger',lastName:'din'}];

function getVal(arr, where, get) {
    for (var i in arr) {
        for (var key in where) {
            if (arr[i][key] == where[key]) {
                if (get == 'fullName') 
                    return arr[i]['firstName'] + ' ' + arr[i]['lastName'];
                else 
                    return arr[i][get];
            }    
        }
    }
}

console.log(getVal(person, {'id':'2'}, 'firstName')); // Tiger
console.log(getVal(person, {'id':'2'}, 'fullName')); // Tiger din
console.log(getVal(person, {'firstName':'Tiger'}, 'id')); // 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is  a simple way out:

From your make an Object like :

```
//var person = {"id":{"fname":"fname_value","lname":"lname_value"}};

var person = {1:{"fname":"John","lname":"doe"},
              2:{"fname":"Tiger","lname":"din"}
             }
// You can Directly access them like:

alert(person[1]["fname"]);
alert(person["2"]["fname"]);
```